# Add layers and layers control to custom map ?

Tags: leaflet

I'm trying to build a custom map for a game and place markers on it , my map is working and my markers too,  but i want to make group of markers , i don't understand how to do , i have tried the example of the website but without success , i got a white screen ... : [layers control leaflet tutorial](https://leafletjs.com/examples/layers-control/)

Here is my code which is working without the Layer Groups and Layers Control
 , is there someone who can show me how to do ? thanks !

https://jsfiddle.net/x8q4eomd/5/

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
              <html>
<head>

    <title>Bless Online Map</title>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="docs/images/favicon.ico" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-Rksm5RenBEKSKFjgI3a41vrjkw4EVPlJ3+OiI65vTjIdo9brlAacEuKOiQ5OFh7cOI1bkDwLqdLw3Zg0cRJAAQ==" crossorigin=""/>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha512-/Nsx9X4HebavoBvEBuyp3I7od5tA0UzAxs+j83KgC8PU0kgB4XiK4Lfe4y4cgBtaRJQEIFCW+oC506aPT2L1zw==" crossorigin=""></script>


    <style>
        html, body {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
        }
        #map {
            width: 5400px;
            height: 5400px;
        }
    </style>


</head>
<body>

<div id='map'></div>

<script>

    var map = L.map('map', {
        crs: L.CRS.Simple,
        minZoom: -3
    });

    var yx = L.latLng;

    var xy = function(x, y) {
        if (L.Util.isArray(x)) {    // When doing xy([x, y]);
            return yx(x[1], x[0]);
        }
        return yx(y, x);  // When doing xy(x, y);
    };
var greenIcon = L.icon({
    iconUrl: 'leaf-green.png',
    shadowUrl: 'leaf-shadow.png',

    iconSize:     [38, 95], // size of the icon
    shadowSize:   [50, 64], // size of the shadow
    iconAnchor:   [22, 94], // point of the icon which will correspond to marker's location
    shadowAnchor: [4, 62],  // the same for the shadow
    popupAnchor:  [-3, -76] // point from which the popup should open relative to the iconAnchor
});

    var bounds = [xy(0, 0), xy(5400, 5400)];
    var image = L.imageOverlay('https://i.imgur.com/h5O086f.jpg', bounds).addTo(map);
    var sol      = xy(2260, 2158);
    var mizar    = xy( 3508, 2690);
    var kruegerZ = xy( 13.4,  56.5);
    var deneb    = xy(218.7,   8.3);

    L.marker(     sol).addTo(map).bindPopup(      'Donjon 1 ');
    L.marker(   mizar).addTo(map).bindPopup(    'Donjon 2');
    L.marker(kruegerZ).addTo(map).bindPopup('Donjon 3');
    L.marker(   deneb).addTo(map).bindPopup(    'Donjon 4');



    map.setView(xy(4000, 1000), 0);

</script>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should also share the code that you say does not work and that reproduces the issue you describe. Otherwise people will not be able to explain why it did not work, hence you miss an opportunity to improve your skills.

Comment: It is difficult to understand what you are ultimately trying to do (why do you want to group things? To toggle their visibility on/off at the same moment?), and the code you are showing does *not* reproduce the "I get a white screen" problem you were describing.

Answer (score -2):

@Adawong. You need to set it in Javascript to add multiple layers in leaflet like this,

```
layers: {
            baselayers: {                    
                topo: {
                    name: "ArcGISStreets",
                    type: "agsBase",
                    layer: "Topographic",
                    visible: true
                },
                osm: {
                    name: 'OpenStreetMap',
                    url: 'http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
                    type: 'xyz'
                     }
            }
```

}

I have used this layers in my Angular-Leaflet-Directive project, and I have created sample JSFiddle to show how Layers works? [Click here](http://jsfiddle.net/sudi065/8nrLkxvg/)

Source for reference: [Browse all sample Angular-Leaflet projects here](http://tombatossals.github.io/angular-leaflet-directive/examples/0000-viewer.html#/layers/simple-example)

Comment: OP does not use Angular.

Comment: Yes, I know, but Javascript can be used as an alternative. Like this, https://leafletjs.com/examples/layers-control/

Comment: Yes, please note that OP already mentions that exact link in their question.